# old Linux Kernel weird behavior

Tags: linux, bash, timeout

I have an old device with a minimal custom linux Kernel. We bought the device from a company around 20 years ago and programmed it to suit our needs.

```
uname -r
2.4.21
```

I have developed a text based UI on the device and am allowing access to it through telnet and serial port.

When connected using telnet, calling `read -s STR` twice, leads to the second read being ignored. This occurs because telnet ends lines with `"\r\n"`.

e.g.:

```
echo "Enter new password: "; read -s password1
echo "Enter new password again: "; read -s password2 #<--this read returns directly
```

so my solution was to read all characters from stdin after each read call. 
However, using serial communication only `"\n"` is sent as a line ending. So I decided to add 1 second timeout to the above read call.

So, I basically ended up with this:

```
echo "Enter new password: "; read -s password1
read -t 1 -n 1000 ignore
echo "Enter new password again: "; read -s password2
read -t 1 -n 1000 ignore
```

And to my surprise, `read -t 1` blocks sometimes. So I ran the following to illustrate this behavior:

```
set -x

while true;
do
read -t 1 -n 10000 STR
echo "timeout"
sleep 5
done
```

The script hangs after 2 loops and only continues when I press enter.

Last I tried the following:

```
set -x
unset STR
while true;
do
read -s -n 1 char
if [[ $char == $'\r' ]]
then
read -s -n 1 ignore
break
elif [[ $char == $'\n' ]]
then
break
fi
STR=$STR$char
done
```

This leads to:

```
++ true
++ read -s -n 1 char
 ]][[ a == \
++ [[ a == \
 ]]
++ STR=a
++ true
++ read -s -n 1 char   <-------- HERE I PRESSED ENTER
 ]][[ '' == \
++ [[ '' == \
 ]]
++ STR=a
++ true
++ read -s -n 1 char
```

So `ENTER` or `"\n"` is being translated to `''`, therefore it does not break out of the loop.

On newer devices, where we have more control over the kernel

```
uname -r
2.6.24.6
```

The issue does not occur, i.e. calling read twice does not lead to the second read call being ignored.

Does anyone have an idea of a work around this issue?

Comment: A couple of things about this sound wrong. First, since the pair is `\r\n`, the first read should include the `\r` at the end of the string stored in the parameter, rather than requiring a second read to clear it. Second, while the telnet protocol may use `\r\n`, those should not be passed on to the underlying shell which receives its input via telnet.

Comment: @chepner it is weird indeed. It seems to me that `\r` is included in the internal field separator (IFS). However, due to the lack of support of basic system commands in the kernels I am unable to print the `IFS`.  I tried `export IFS=' \t\n'`, but to no avail.
BTW, is there another way to test for `\r` or `\n` other than `[[ $char == $'\r' ]] || [[ $char == $'\n' ]]`? or maybe even print the characters received in hex?

Comment: I don't think kernel version is important at all. Can you tell us the shell you're using and it's version?

Comment: @mkalkov GNU bash, version 2.05.8(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1):

The terminal is translating every '\r' into '\n', so you see no difference between the two.  You can use `stty igncr` to ignore completely the CR.  With that, your first approach should work:

```
stty igncr
echo "Enter new password: "; read -s password1
echo "Enter new password again: "; read -s password2
stty sane
```

The last `stty sane` may not be necessary.

If that approach does not work, try using `stty -icrnl` instead (but that way, `$password1` and `$password2` will have a `\r` at the end; you can suppress it with `tr -d '\r'`).